# with parse notification my app crash

Tags: android-activity, push-notification, parse-platform

My application was working perfectly fine until the day I involved Parse notifications.  Now my apps crashes if idle for 2 min.  The following is the code, can any one support me?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        }
        // Create the WebView
        else {
            startWebView("file:///android_asset/www/quotes.html");
        }
        try {
                Parse.initialize(this, "***************", "**********");
            PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
            ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        } catch(Exception exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: You can solve it easily using this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838855/android-doesnt-receive-push-notification-from-parse-push-when-app-is-closed